# Split string with space and forward slash by forward slash

Tags: c#

I wan't to split the string by forward slash

My current code looks like this:

```
  string value = "Ctws Cwts/Rotc/Lts Ctws";
  string[] tokens = value.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  foreach (var token in tokens)
  {
      Console.Write(token);
  }
```

The output is this one: **"Cwts Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts Cwts"**

Now I want my ouput to be this one: **"Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts"**

Edited:

Some of the answers suggest that I will used Distinct()

What if the value is: **"Something1 Cwts/Rotc/Lts Something2"**

The output should be the same: **"Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  string[] tokens = value
              .Split(new char[] { '/', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Distinct();
```

Also don't forget to include *space* to seperators

According to your edit you can do the following if you want exacly these values: `"Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts"` for all inputs

```
var values = new List<string> { "Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts" };
string[] tokens = value
              .Split(new char[] { '/', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Where(t => values.Contains(t))
              .Distinct();
```

Comment: +1 i think you need to use both forward slash and space as delimeters.but `Distinct()` is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi yeah just noticed that.

Comment: Tried your solution and it's not working. I've got the same output. And also, what if, the given value is "something1 Cwts/Rotc/Lts Something2".

Comment: @user2930551 do you want exacly these values for all strings? `"Cwts Rotc Lts"`or you just want distinct results?

Comment: @user2930551 me too.try again

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple character by which you want to split the string. You can use one of the overload of the [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. To remove the duplicate entries you can use [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

So here is your statement

```
string[] tokens = value.Split(new char[] { '/',' ' },
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct().ToArray();
```

***Edit***: After your editing the question seems to be little confusing to me that what you want to achieve. What I understand it, You have the list of string which you want to find in the single string which contains `/` and `spaces`.

For that you can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
List<string> requiredValues = new List<string> { "Cwts", "Rotc", "Lts" };

var tokens = requiredValues.Intersect(value.Split(new char[] { '/', ' ' }, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: The use of the Intersect operator is an elegant solution but it makes the call to Distinct redundant, and the call to ToList is also unneeded.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes you right. just forgot to remove. ccp mistake :) check the edited post

Answer (score 1):

```
 string value = "Ctws Cwts/Rotc/Lts Ctws";
 var terms = new HashSet<String> { "Ctws", "Rotc", "Lts" };

 var tokens = 
     from s in value.Split(new [] { ' ','/' },
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     group s by s into g 
     where terms.Contans(g.Key)
     select g.Key;
```

This should take care of the splitting filtering and removal of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct with 2 params

```
 var tokens = value
              .Split(new char[] { '/', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Distinct();
```