# Check a pattern in a string then convert it to upper case

Tags: c#, regex, string

I was not clear with my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658079/split-string-with-space-and-forward-slash-by-forward-slash/21658088#21658088)

I have a list: `new List<string> { "lts", "mts", "cwts", "rotc" };`

Now I wan't to check a pattern in string that starts or ends with a forward slash like this: **"cTws/Rotc/lTs"** or **"SomethingcTws cWtS/Rotc rOtc"**.

and convert to upper case only the string that starts/ends with a forward slash based on the list that I have.

So the output should be: **"CWTS/ROTC/LTS"**, **"SomethingcTws CWTS/ROTC rOtc"**

I modified [Sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658650/2930551)'s answer:

```
        List<string> replacementValues = new List<string>
        {
            "cwts",
            "mts",
            "rotc",
            "lts"
        };
        string pattern = string.Format(@"\G({0})/?", string.Join("|", replacementValues.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
        Regex regExp = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string value = "Cwts/Rotc Somethingcwts1 Cwts/Rotc/lTs";
        string result = regExp.Replace(value, s => s.Value.ToUpper());
```

Result: **CWTS/ROTC Somethingcwts1 Cwts/Rotc/lTs**

The desired output should be: **CWTS/ROTC Somethingcwts1 CWTS/ROTC/LTS**

Comment: That's an entirely different question than your previous one. Can you share your attempts at solving this?

Comment: I added additional examples

Comment: `string strToReplace = "Somethingg1 Cwts/Rotc/Lts Cwts";
            Console.WriteLine(strToReplace.Replace("Cwts", "CWTS").Replace("Rotc","ROTC") );`. This code should solve your purpose.

Comment: I reworded my question.

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using Regex, which I'm not really good with, I'm doing split by space then split by "/" then rejoin the strings

```
string val = "Somethingrotc1 cWts/rOtC/lTs Cwts";
List<string> replacementValues = new List<string> 
    { 
        "lts", "mts", 
        "cwts", "rotc"
    };
string[] tokens = val.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string result = string.Join(" ", tokens.Select(t =>
            {
                // Now split by "/"
                string[] ts = t.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (ts.Length > 1)
                {
                    t = string.Join("/", ts.Select(x => replacementValues.Contains(x.ToLower()) ? x.ToUpper() : x));
                }
                return t;
            }));
```

Output: **Somethingrotc1 CWTS/ROTC/LTS Cwts**

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the specific words in the string to Upper case. Then you can use `Regex` to achieve it.

```
string value = "Somethingg1 Cwts/Rotc/Lts Cwts";
var replacementValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                   {
                     {"Cwts","CWTS"},
                     {"Rotc","ROTC"},
                     {"Lts","LTC"}
                   };
var regExpression = new Regex(String.Join("|", replacementValues.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
var outputString = regExpression.Replace(value, s => replacementValues[s.Value]);
```

Comment: In your solution the last part of the string is in upper case: "Something1 CWTS/ROTC/LTC CWTS" should be like this "Something1 CWTS/ROTC/LTC Cwts"

Comment: So do you want to replace only first occurrence of string to upper case?

Comment: Not first occurrence but pattern like **"[Value1]/[Value2]/[Value3]"** where I have a list of string to check in that pattern `List<string> { "cwts", "rotc", "lts" }` and convert it to upper case. The value could be **"Something1 rOtC/cWts Cwts"** and convert it to **"Something1 ROTC/CWTS Cwts"**